# ¿Fallo con mouseListener?

Tags: java, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo una ventana donde tengo 2 paneles uno ubicado del lado izquierdo y otro del lado derecho en el izquierdo tengo imágenes de logos de marcas y en panel derecho quiero ubicar imágenes de productos de las marcas cuando el mouse pase por encima de las imágenes de las marcas ejecuto el programa y no me aparecen las imágenes hasta que encojo la ventana aparecen no se porque suceda esto EN VERDAD NECESITO AYUDA:

```
        public class Catalogo {

                private JFrame ventana;
                private JPanel panelD, panelI;
                private JLabel img1, img2, img3, img4, img5;
                String ruta = "src/img/";
            public void atributos() {
                    ventana.setSize(900, 385);
                    ventana.setResizable(true);
                    panelI.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelI, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                    panelI.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    panelD.setBackground(Color.red);
                    panelD.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    img1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ruta + "Aston.jpg"));
                    img2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ruta + "mclaren.jpg"));
                    img3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ruta + "Ferrari.jpg"));
                    img4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ruta + "Koeni.jpg"));
                    img5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ruta + "pruebita.jpg"));

        public void armado() {
            ventana.add(panelD);
            ventana.add(panelI, BorderLayout.WEST);
            panelI.add(img1);
            panelI.add(img2);
            panelI.add(img3);
            panelI.add(img4);
        }
    public void ecuchas() {
            Escucha_Raton esc = new Escucha_Raton();
            img1.addMouseListener(esc);
        }
 class Escucha_Raton implements MouseListener {
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            panelD.add(img5);   
        }
}
```

Comment: Donde llamas a los metodos?

Comment: a tengo un método donde los mando a llamar solo que puse solamente el código donde creí que podría estar el fallo.